# Buscar un elemento en un array de arrays en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quiero obtener un elemento de un array de arays que coincida con un dato, en este caso el primer dato de mi array, que hace referencia al id de cada array.

```
var data = 
     [
        [1, 'darinel', 24, '9a3853'],
        [2, 'oscar', 19, 'ecf03c'],
        [3, 'Alexander', 15, 'aab418']
     ];
```

Recibo un dato, en este caso el id, por medio de un formulario; tengo los siguientes datos:

```js
var data = 
     [
        [1, 'darinel', 24, '9a3853'],
        [2, 'oscar', 19, 'ecf03c'],
        [3, 'Alexander', 15, 'aab418']
     ];

var id = 1;

var people = data.filter((element) => element === id);

console.log(people);
```

Pero esto me devuelve vacío; estoy pensando en recorrer por medio de un FOR aunque no tengo claro cómo hacerlo.
Se me olvidaba mencionar que el array de arrays puede variar y puede tener diferentes dimensiones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El filter te devolvería un nuevo array con un único elemento adentro que ya es un array.
Sería así, donde 0 sería el indice del array que estás recorriendo dentro del array padre.

```
var people = data.filter((element) => element[0] === id);
```

Esto te devolvería un array con el array recorrido adentro, es decir:
people sería igual a: [[1, "darinel", 24, "9a3853"]], y para entrar a eso deberías entrar a este array en la posición 0 y luego la posición de cada dato, ej: 0 el id, 1 el nombre, 2 lo otro.
De esta manera: people[0][1] - Esto te traería el nombre.

Capaz esto te sirve.

```
var data = [
  [1, "darinel", 24, "9a3853"],
  [2, "oscar", 19, "ecf03c"],
  [3, "Alexander", 15, "aab418"],
];

var id = 1;
var result = ""; // Declaro auxiliar para depositar los datos en un string común
for (const item of data) { // recorro cada array dentro del array padre
  if (item[0] === id) { // en cada array ve si en indice 0 o sea el id es igual id
//Si fue igual concateno en un string su id, su nombre y el último dato
    result = item[0] + " " + item[1] + " " + item[2]
  }
}
//Finalmente muestro el string depositado en result
console.log(result);
```

---

Otra opción es en vez de generar un string con todo concatenado usar un objeto, quedaría así:

```
var data = [
    [1, "darinel", 24, "9a3853"],
    [2, "oscar", 19, "ecf03c"],
    [3, "Alexander", 15, "aab418"],
  ];
  
  var id = 1;
  var result = {}; // Declaro auxiliar para depositar los datos en un string común
  for (const item of data) { // recorro cada array dentro del array padre
    if (item[0] === id) { // en cada array ve si en indice 0 o sea el id es igual id
  //Agrego datos al objeto result
      result.id = item[0]
      result.nombre = item[1]
      result.tercerDato=item[2]
    }
  }
  //Finalmente muestro el objeto result
  console.log(result);
```

Esto devuelve un objeto así: {id: 1, nombre: "darinel", tercerDato: 24}
Entonces ahora puedes entrar a result.id, o result.nombre o result.tercerDato(no sabía que era, supongo que color por hex de 6 digitos)

Si cambias el valor de la variable id te traerá la persona con ese id, yo los deposité en un string, pero puedes hacer con los datos lo que desees en ese mismo lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que este pequeño código te ayude o te de alguna idea que puedas implementar en tu código.

```js
    const btn = [...document.querySelectorAll("button")];

    let info = [
      [1,"Nombre: Tomás", "edad: 25 años"],
      [2,"Nombre: Martina", "edad: 27 años"]
    ];
    
    let info2 = [
      [1,"Nombre: Tomás", "edad: 25 años"],
      [2,"Nombre: Martina", "edad: 27 años"]
    ];

    btn.forEach(key=>{//obtengo los botones
      key.onclick =()=>{ // le agrego la función click a cada elemento botón
          const data_info = key.dataset.info; // obtengo el dataset info del elemento
         if(info[key.id][data_info] == info2[key.id][data_info]){ // verificar que el valor de array obtenido (array info) sea igual al array info2
            console.log(true)
            console.log(info[key.id].join(" ").replace("1", "")) // muestro el resultado del array en string
         }else{
            console.log(false) // no es igual
         }
      }
    });
```

```html
    <button id="0" data-info="1">información 1</button>
    <button id="1" data-info="2">información 2</button>
```

Comment: Gracias para otro enfoque servira de maravilla, quiza en un futuro me encuentre con un problema similar y me sea util, gracias @Daniel

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento de este código: ten en cuenta que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el OP, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad, y puede que algunos no comprendan su funcionamiento. _[es.so] no es un repositorio de código_. Lee [answer].